# Changing the Center of a leaflet open street map

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, openstreetmap

I'm initializing a map using leaflet(openstreetmaps) in angular and setting a center that the user sees when opening the site. How can i change the center so the map rotates to the new coordinates on click of e.g. a button? Setting a new center doesn't appear to do anything, neither do i want to reload the site itself. Thanks!

```
private initMap(): void {

    this.map = L.map('map', {
      center: [48.1841234, 11.5877796],
      zoom: 16
    });}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `map.flyTo([latlng])` or `map.panTo([latlng])`

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#map-panto